# Forcing a program to flush file contents to disk

Tags: linux, unix

I have to debug a program that writes a log file. It takes time for the actual log file to be generated because it takes a while to flush the contents to disk. On top of that, the log file is on a mounted Unix drive on my windows machine. I was wondering if there is a command to make the operating system flush the written contents to disk. Does it also take a while for the file to be updated on the mounted drive in windows?

PS. I actually; don't want to go in and edit the program.

Ted

Comment: [`fsync(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fsync.html) is the way, as long as the underlying device and filesystem support it.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the following APIs:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setvbuf/
- fsync

Also see the ever-great [eat my data: how everybody gets file IO wrong](http://www.linux.org.au/conf/2007/talk/278.html)